# ImportError: cannot import name 'StableDiffusionPipeline' from 'diffusers'

Tags: python, deep-learning

ImportError : Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [96],

in <cell line: 3>()

1 import torch

2 from torch import autocast

----> 3 from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline

**ImportError: cannot import name 'StableDiffusionPipeline' from 'diffusers' (E:\Py\env\lib\site-packages\diffusers_*init*_.py)**

i've installed diffusers latest version. how do i solve this?

Comment: Did you use one of these for installation?
For PyTorch with `pip`:
`pip install --upgrade diffusers[torch]`.
With conda:
`conda install -c conda-forge diffusers`

Answer (score 16):

Reinstalling `diffusers` solves the problem for me.

```
pip uninstall diffusers
pip install diffusers
```

Comment: did not help to me. I tried different versions, but not working . I get: ImportError: cannot import name 'StableDiffusionUpscalePipeline' from partially initialized module 'diffusers' (most likely due to a circular import)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated April 2023:** There are some version conflict problems that's why you cannot run `StableDiffusionPipeline`. I also tried `pip install --upgrade diffusers[torch]` and `conda install -c conda-forge diffusers` but didn't work for me Double check the diffuser version.

**Solution**

```
git clone https://github.com/LambdaLabsML/lambda-diffusers.git
cd lambda-diffusers
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install diffusers==0.11.1
```